# Voltage and Current source

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current

What is the difference between current and voltage source.
Why is it that when using current source we have to connect the load in parallel and should not connect it in series

Comment: I hope the Wikipedia page on [current source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_source) clarifies your question. If not, please add more details to your question.

Comment: A current source will give constant current, while a voltage source will provide constant potential difference across its ends

Comment: "Why is it that when using current source we have to connect the load in parallel and should not connect it in series" Where have you got this idea?.

Comment: he is propably reffering to the Norton equivalence...

Answer (score 0):

The $i$ vs $v$ characteristics of a current source and a voltage source (ideal battery) are shown below.

[image]

Note that for a voltage (current) source the voltage (current) is constant irrespective of the magnitude or direction of the current (voltage).

Comment: Thanks, why is it that we always connect load in parallel to current source